# Webmin Port Forwarding

Tags: 12.04, networking, iptables

I have not been able to figure this out at all.

I have 1 Lan IP address and 5 external static IPs:

- eth0: 10.0.0.1 - internal lan ip and router IP.
- eth1: xx.xx.xx.217 - external
- eth2: xx.xx.xx.218 - external
- eth3: xx.xx.xx.219 - external
- eth4: xx.xx.xx.220 - external
- eth5: xx.xx.xx.221 - external

Currently outgoing traffic is is defaulting to use eth4.
Currently I am using webmin.

POSTROUTING eth0 eth4 and eth1 for Masquerade.

Currently I want to forward web traffic from port 80 to IP 10.0.1.220.
Web traffic only comes in on eth1 and nothing else, so I want the rule to apply to only that interface.

I am sure this is possible, I just don't know how. Any help would be appreciated. I have looked at guides and googled this but I can't find anything on multiwan solutions.

Let me know if you need any more information from me.

Also I have business class internet so they are not blocking any traffic at all.

Comment: Are you using 6 NIC cards?

Comment: I have 7 nics available total. 2 on board, 2 2nic cards, 1 1nic card. Each static IP get's its own nic

Comment: what version of Ubuntu is this?